# Nofollow all external links - yes or no?

Tags: hyperlink, seo, smo

I am working with a company that is trying to build their online authority and they want to avoid any penalties from Google and other major search engines.

The site is a social network (adult related) and users can create public profile, post links, images, etc.  It is an adult social network for people that want to make money talking on the phone.

So the question is, is it a good idea to nofollow all external links?  Because it is hard to gauge the quality of sites that we may be linking out to and I don't want to have any issues with this..

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question that does not meet the requirements listed in [the SEO tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The safe route would be, yes, to add `nofollow` to all of your outgoing links if you're going to allow users to be able to insert any link they wish.

A lot of large social networks and forums do this and have no issues.

I hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) on Google suggests you should nofollow untrusted user links.

> If you can't or don't want to vouch for the content of pages you link
> to from your site — for example, untrusted user comments or guestbook
> entries — you should nofollow those links. This can discourage
> spammers from targeting your site, and will help keep your site from
> inadvertently passing PageRank to bad neighborhoods on the web.

I'd probably keep your own links as follow, and make some effort to seek out and remove dodgy links, though - nofollow does not protect your users.